# Definition of $\log z $

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume I want to define an analytic branch of $\log z $ in the region $D(i,1)$ which is the disk centered at $i $ with radius $1$.

Since the multivalued $\log z $ given by

$$ \log z
= \log(re^{i\theta})
= \log|r| + i\operatorname{Arg}(re^{i\theta})
= \log|r| + i(\theta+2\pi k) $$

I'll have to specify which $k $ I'm taking.

So, it seems natural to me to exclude the negative imaginary axis, i.e., for and $ z $ we'll take $ \operatorname{Arg}(z)\in\left(-\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{3}{2}\pi\right) $.

My questions are:

1. Is this means that I defined $\log z $ on the whole plane excpet for the negative part of the imaginary axis? (is this region even simply connected?)
2. How can I show that this definition actually defines an analytic function? it is obvious that

   $$ e^{\log\left(z\right)}
   = e^{\log|r|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)}
   = e^{\log|r|} \cdot e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(z)}
   =|r|e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(z)}
   =z $$

   But the same equations I wrote could be valid for any definition of the $\log $, how exactly the choice of the range for $\theta $ being expressed here? and how can I show that this function is analytic?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just take the principal value $\log $ and restrict it to $D(i,1)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the way you defined it, you don't have to restrict yourself to $D(\mathrm i,1)$. It's valid for the whole slit plane, with the slit being the non-positive imaginary axis (not just the negative imaginary axis, since $0$ also needs to be excluded). This is indeed simply connected. The upper half plane is homeomorphic to a slit plane (with the non-negative real axis missing) via the homeomorphism $z\mapsto z^2$, and the two slit planes are clearly homeomorphic. Also, the half plane is homeomorphic to the entire plane (which is simply connected), so the slit plane is, too. And since homeomorphisms preserve simply connectedness, the slit plane is simply connected.
2. Your function
   $$\log:\mathbb C\backslash[0,-\mathrm i\infty)\to\{z\in\mathbb C~\vert~\operatorname{Im}z\in(-\frac12\pi,\frac32\pi)\}$$
   is the inverse of
   $$\exp:\{z\in\mathbb C~\vert~\operatorname{Im}z\in(-\frac12\pi,\frac32\pi)\}\to \mathbb C\backslash[0,-\mathrm i\infty),$$
   which is analytic, bijective, and has nowhere vanishing derivative. As such, it's inverse is also analytic (also with nowhere vanishing derivative, btw.).

Comment: Is the definition $ f\left(z\right)=\intop_{i}^{z}\frac{1}{\omega}d\omega+i\frac{\pi}{2} $ equivalent to the one I wrote in the post?

Comment: Yes, it is. All branches of $\log$, yours included, are antiderivatives of $\frac1z$, and on simply connected domains, antiderivatives can at most differ by a constant summand. Since both $f$ and $\log$ are antiderivatives of the same function, and $f(\mathrm i)=\mathrm i\frac\pi2=\log(\mathrm i)$, they don't differ at all.

Comment: By the way, can two branches of $\log $ agree on some values? because I thought about it, if we restrict the non-positive part of the imaginary axis (i.e $arg\in (-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$) and if we restrict the non positive part of the real axis (the principal branch, $arg \in (-\pi,\pi) $ , it seems like in both cases $\log i=i\pi/2 $

Comment: Yes, that's possible. In fact, you can "glue" the domains of different branches together at the places where they agree to obtain a kind of spiral surface on which all branches of the logarithm can find their place. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg

Answer (score 2):

1. It indeed means that you defined $\log(\cdot)$ on the complex plane except for the non-positive imaginary axis, i.e., the region

   $$ \mathcal{D} = \mathbb{C} \setminus (-i[0, \infty)). $$

   To show that $\mathcal{D}$ is simply connected, you may verify that $\mathcal{D}$ is a [star-shaped domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain), in the sense that there exists a point $z_0 \in \mathcal{D}$ such that every $z \in \mathcal{D}$ can be joined to $z_0$ through a line segment in $\mathcal{D}$.
2. One way is to verify that your definition satisfies the Cauchy–Riemann equations. Note that

   $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log |r| = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \log |r| = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} $$

   and that any branch of $\arg(\cdot)$ satisfies

   $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\arg(z) = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\arg(z) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}. $$

   Alternatively, you may realize your $\log(\cdot)$ as an inverse of an appropriate restriction of $\exp(\cdot)$. Together with the fact that $\exp(\cdot)$ has nowhere-vanishing derivative, the inverse function theorem for analytic functions will guarantee the analyticity of the inverse.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. A few questions if I may. As I understand, in order to show that this function is analytic, showing that Cauchy-Riemann equations satisfied is not enough, since we also need to prove that this function is $\mathbb{R} $- differentiable, or alternatively that the partial derivatives are continuous. Also, how can I see that any branch of $arg $ satisfies the equations you wrote? Thanks!

Comment: @euler0.0, $\log r=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)$ is clearly smooth on $\mathcal{D}$. Now for $\arg(\cdot)$, the computation will depend on you how it is defined in your context. One way to do is to realize $\arg$, at least locally, using the conventional inverse trigonometric functions. For example, with your choice of $\arg$, we may write $$\arg(x+iy)=\begin{cases}\arctan(y/x),&x>0\\\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x/y),&y>0\\\pi+\arctan(x/y),&x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Alternatively, note that any branch of $\theta=\arg(z)$ arises from the polar coordinates $$(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta),$$ which is smooth and has the invertible Jacobian everywhere. Then the inverse function theorem shows that any local inverse of this transformation is also smooth and even allows to compute partial derivatives of $\theta$.